# VNImageRequestHandler init with pixels data

Tags: objective-c, coreml

I would like to use a VNImageRequestHandler with raw pixels data. The method initWithData:options: of VNImageRequestHandler is not documented, and I can't find any example using this. What is the accepted format, and what is this "options" parameter ?

Apple documentation (empty) page : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2866551-initwithdata?language=objc

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Note that a `CVPixelBuffer` is basically a wrapper around raw pixel data. You can easily create one that points at your own pixel data using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()`.